# How do I detect a current URL in Flash?

Tags: flash, streaming, external, podcast

I'm trying to create an application that contains all my favourite podcasts. 
When I click on a specific podcast feed, all the different episodes shows up in a list.
Now, here's the problem - How do I detect the URL for the mp3 within each episodes headline so I can play it?
Or if you have other info about streaming external media, please be my guest!

Right, so I got this simple URL request function that loads the information to another function. So far, so good. Yaaay! And then, there's this onLoaded function I've got, that creates an XMLList where all the episodes are showing up. Ive a bunch of other lines of code that I don't quite understand, that I copied from Adobes Podcast Player example(which is way to complex for me). help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d15.html

Comment: Nice start to a question, however more information and elaboration is required. Maybe include a short list explaining how you got to where you are now, as I don't understand how your list is generated or how the podcasts that make up the list get into your application :)

Comment: Of course! I'm not used to this. Uhmm...

Comment: No rush, I'll check back every half an hour or so.

Comment: Right, so I got this simple URL request function that loads the information to another function. So far, so good. Yaaay! And then, there's this onLoaded function I've got, that creates an XMLList where all the episodes are showing up. Ive a bunch of other lines of code that I don't quite understand, that I copied from Adobes Podcast Player example. Never worked with sound in AS before, but I wouldn't call me a comlplete rookie :)

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d15.html

Comment: However, I only need the basic features. Not the descriptions, or images, or the loader bar etc. Just play, pause and stop would do it for me.

Comment: Thank you man! Really sweet of you :)